# field update witchout loosing previuos field data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having problem updating my field data. For example I have field with data "runner" and I want to update field to "runner, swimmer".In other words I want that my field would never delete previuos data. But now after update I am getting from "runner" to "swimmer" only.

---

My code now:

```
    function updateUserField($username, $field, $value) {
    $q = "UPDATE " . TBL_USERS . " SET " . $field . " = '$value' WHERE username = '$username'";
    return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
}
```

---

Thanks for help! And sorry for bad english.

Comment: You need to use the CONCAT() function in MySQL for string concatenation. See answer.

Comment: Please note that you're vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This is a big security risk. I'd advise you to move to PDO or mysqli to prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong idea.  The right way to store lists in a relational database is to use a junction table.  This would have one row per user and per "field".  In your case, the table would have at least three columns `UserId`, `Field`, `Value`.

Then, the "update" would look like:

```
insert into UserFields (UserId, Field, Value)
    values ($UserId, @Field, $Value);
```

(Of course, you should be using mysqli_ and parameterized queries, but that is another matter.)

Don't get into the habit of storing lists as strings, when SQL offers a very good method for storing lists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the CONCAT() function in MySQL for string concatenation:

`UPDATE TBL_USERS SET $field = CONCAT($field, '$value') WHERE username = $username;`